# CSS stops working when I do changes on website

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, overriding

I am trying to style the nickname of users in discord for myself (local changes). I added a border to the nickname style "`.username-1A8OIy`" I tried it and it worked. The problem is when I add simple line of code in my override file **the whole CSS in the website stops working** like there is no styling sheet at all.
Here is the code I am trying to add:

```
.username-1A8OIy {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

**Whenever I refresh the page**, I should see my changes still there. But the only thing I see is just HTML website with no styling sheet at all. And when I remove the code I added, everything comes back to normal.
Is there a problem in my code or something? What exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since an override replaces the original you need to keep the original and add your changes below.

Comment: @wOxxOm I do only edit the original style directly. Not making any new CSS I just go to inspector and insert a new line that have the code ```.username-1A8OIy {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}``` without changing anything else and all original CSS is still there.